# Initialize states after LSTM Model training on one time series data

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I am currently building LSTM model (sequence length:30 days) for the application of Predictive maintenance. I have several machines that have failed and I have their time series data which are different in length. I have couple of questions regarding this.

(1) I recently cam across the concept of stateful and stateless in LSTM models and I am wondering if it is a good idea to initialize hidden layer states each time after model training on one machine's time series data?

(2) Can I keep shuffle = True in this case to stop model learning sequence dependencies?

I am relatively new in this area so please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.